# Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

The error:

```
>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: DrawShape.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
```

The configuration in Configuration Manager seems correct:

[image: Configuration Manager]

This is the code of the project I am trying to build:

https://github.com/chrispellett/Xamarin-Forms-Shape

---

What I have tried so far:

Changing from Any CPU to x86 and back.

Setting the Build checkbox to false and then back to true.

Comment: Select **Deploy** also from Configuration Manager for android project.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much. The error (Project not selected to *build* for this solution configuration) was a bit confusing, plus the answers on this error were all pointing out to the *Build* checkbox, not the *Deploy* one. Being new to Xamarin I didn't know that *Deploy* on Android needed to be checked, and the project in git didn't have it checked for some reason (when creating a new Visual Studio project, the checkbox is indeed checked by default).

Answer (score 201):

As [Kowalski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017153/kowalski) said, You must check Deploy Option on Configuration Manager. RightClick on the solution and select Configuration Manager. Then Check Deploy Option for the startup Project.
As this image

[image]

Comment: Yes we need to check `deploy` checkbox

Comment: I've been facing with this in a CI build server and for me was enough to check build column (it was unchecked)

Comment: I was facing the same issue while building the window service through CI build, and just checked the build column and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks but why is this even a thing?? such an obvious fix for VS

Comment: I had been looking for hours to solve this in VS 2019, but how would that project ever get unchecked in there ? I am 100% sure it was not me

Comment: What does it mean when the Deploy button is disabled as it is in my case?

Answer (score 27):

go To Build => Configuration Manager . then check the deploy checkbox for the startup project . 
Ps. make sure to select your startup project by right clicking on the project => set as startup project

Comment: What does it mean when the Deploy button is disabled as it is in my case?

Answer (score 6):

Select Deploy also from Configuration Manager for android project

Answer (score 1):

Select the device deployment project from Configuration manager.

here it is the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x02cw.png)