# Using MSBuild at command-line to produce VSIX does not error, does not build VSIX - but IDE does. How to debug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, vsix

I have a VSIX extension which I have migrated to a new solution (basically to remove older projects targeting older VS versions no longer supported by my company) and to simplify the codebase for ease of maintenance.

Within the IDE, it does not matter if I set the active configuration to Debug|x86 or Release|x86, it will build a VSIX artifact OK. All good so far.

If I use
`MSBuuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 -restore -detailedSummary MyExtension.sln`
it will build without any errors, **but no VSIX is produced.**

I have poured over the terminal output and there are no warnings/errors and the DLL output of projects in the solution are produced.

I did read the following:
[Project not selected to build for this solution configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675012/project-not-selected-to-build-for-this-solution-configuration)
The option to click deploy from the above link is not available for my VSIX - all the deploy options are disabled.

I have searched S.O. for similar issues regarding a VSIX not being produced, but none seem apt.

How should I debug this? What is different about a command-line MSBuild from the in-IDE build? Hopefully somebody has had a similar experience and can let me know what was causal for them, so that I can give something a try.

**Update 1:**
It transpired that although I was targeting .NET Framework 4.6, some .csproj references copied over from the migrated project had entries for `net472`, despite NuGet packages themselves being selected for compatibility with .NET Framework 4.6.

I had to manually edit a few .csproj files. There were some reference issues in associated projects that then needed fixing.

The residual issue now is as follows:
The in-IDE build fails with a single error...
`A PackageReference to Microsoft.Build.* without ExcludeAssets="runtime" exists in your project. This will cause MSBuild assemblies to be copied to your output directory, causing your application to load them at runtime. To use the copy of MSBuild registered by MSBuildLocator, set ExcludeAssets="runtime" on the MSBuild PackageReferences. To disable this check, set the property DisableMSBuildAssemblyCopyCheck=true in your project file (not recommended as you must distributed all of MSBuild + associated toolset). Package(s) referenced: Microsoft.Build.Framework`

So I grepped my source code folder for `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build` and only a single project was in the result list. When I checked this project file, the entry in question did have `ExcludeAssets="runtime"` so I am unsure why the error is reported. I have tried project cleans followed by rebuild, or deleting `bin` and `obj` folders before building, to no avail.

I guess my question now is whether `<Package Include="Microsoft.Build` are relevant, since these are not `<ReferencePackage Include` elements as mentioned in the error message.

**Update 2:**
I hang my head in shame. PBKAC regarding Update 1 error. I had sent a copy of the code to a build engineer who committed it to a branch in our VCS. I then cloned this branch to a different location, and copy+pasted my more recent changes over the top. However, the grep tool (AstroGrep) I was using was still pointing at the older location not in the VCS. The older location contained package references with `ExcludeAssets="runtime"` as required. However, the newer location did not. Once I noticed this, I corrected it by editing the faulty .csproj file and the error from **Update 1** went away.

However, I still appear to have the original issue the question is about.

I am awaiting my company's security team to approve the use of MSBuildLog so that I can get more detail and hopefully find the cause.

One other commenter suggest moving to solution PackageReference build rather than using packages.config. There is a question as to why this is needed. I am aware this seems like it could create a significant amount of extra work due to: [this](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5899) for which there are workarounds, but the commenter mentioned a "need" to use NuGet this way, when I think it is optional. I wish to understand more before committing to such a change.

Comment: msbuild src\GUI\EFCorePowerTools.sln /p:configuration=Release  /p:DeployExtension=false /p:ZipPackageCompressionLevel=normal /v:m

(make sure your extension project is a classic .csproj)

Comment: @ErikEJ Please see Update 1. I am not sure your ```msbuild``` command-line is effectively any different from mine. ```DeployExtension``` and ```ZipPackageCompressionLevel``` default to what you show. This leaves ```/v:m``` which I believe is equivalent to setting verbosity to minimal? Or did you intend something else? Since I need to ensure correct NuGet packages, I include ```-restore``` and ```-detailedSummary``` will add commentary about what MSBuild is doing.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? More importantly, in VS menu, go to Tools => Options... => NuGet Package Manager => General. Under "Package Management" is "Default package management format" set to "PackageReference" or "Packages.config"? It needs to be "PackageReference"

Comment: add /bl to your msbuild command line. Download/install the MSBuild Structured Log Viewer from https://msbuildlog.com, to analyze the resulting msbuild.binlog. If it isn't obvious, create a new project, do the same, and use that working projects .binlog as a baseline.

Comment: @user9938 VS2019 is what is being used to create the VSIX, which targets 2015-2019 via .NET Framework v4.6. As projects were ported (read copied and fixed up) from old spaghetti code solutions**, they were using packages.config and still are. May I ask why "it needs to be PacakageReference"? **=previously there were multiple solutions each targeting a different .NET Framework and some horrific IDL manipulation in the build which was run multiple times to produce version-specific VSIX installers supporting back to 2008, when only 1 VSIX installer is now required to support 2015-2019.

Comment: @EdDore Thanks for this tip. I will give a try to see what can be learnt.

Comment: @EdDore I may not be able to try MSBuildLog. My company likes to check all s/w for potential malicious code and MSBuildLog appears to be flagged by VirusTotal as containing Trojan.Malware.300983.susgen Unless this is confirmed as a false positive by my company's security team, it will not be downloaded.

Comment: According to [Restore packages using Package Restore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-using-msbuild), one can restore packages that use "packages.config" using msbuild:  _starting with MSBuild 16.5+, packages.config projects_. Open "Developer Command Prompt for 2019" and type `msbuild -version`. If you're using >= v16.5, then add `-p:RestorePackagesConfig=true` to your original msbuild command. Ex: `msbuild "C:\Temp\MySolutionName\MySolutionName.sln" -t:Build -p:Configuration=Release -detailedSummary -p:RestorePackagesConfig=true -restore`

Comment: See [MSBuild and package restore with packages.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956184/msbuild-and-package-restore-with-packages-config) for more information.

Comment: @user9938 Thanks for the information. I have been away, but also returned and resolved the issue. It was not something I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is one of those things where it's a case of user beware.

When using NuGet, it is possible for it to appear to have succeeded in updating a NuGet reference, but unless one checks the underlying `packages.config` meticulously, you may not be getting what you think.

As I am migrating a solution that used `packages.config` instead of `<Project Reference .../>` elements in `.csproj` files, I have been caught out by IDE default behaviour changes.

NuGet seems to update the `.csproj` using `<PacakageReference.../>` elements by default. But this does not amend the `packages.config` entries that may already exist. As such, I ended up with a mish-mash that MSBuild seemed confused about at build time. Rather than throw an error, it just did not build what was expected.

The old `packages.config` files had entries targeting .NET Framework of `net472` in some cases. I was adding NuGet references to earlier versions for `net46` since this is what I need to target now, and this resulted in the problem behaviour, since any unchanged `net472` entries were no good for producing the build output.

Since the project needs to support VS2015 also, I need to rely on `packages.config` approach and not `<PackageReference.../>` approach, which was not updating older references in the expected way.

As such, I had to remove the NuGet `<PacakgeReference.../>` and re-introduce correct package versions in `packages.config`. Once these were all correct, the VSIX built OK.